# Multiple connection to a local HSQLDB - Java

Tags: java, database, connection, hsqldb

I did some research on this matter but didn't find anything conclusive. I'm using a local `HSQLDB` and here is how i'm connecting to this database:

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:file:src/database/db", "SA", "");
```

I want to be able to make multiple connections. Why? I have two java applications. One is displaying data from this database (only reading) and the other is adding data to this database (reading and writting). I may need to have several instances of each application. But when a connection is already active and that I run a second instance of my app, it doesn't run and give me an error 10sec later:

```
Database lock acquisition failure: lockFile
```

Is there a way to achive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start an HSQLDB Server with your database and connect to it from different processes:

http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/running-chapt.html#rgc_hsql_server

Detailed information:

http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/listeners-chapt.html

Comment: I can't use a server because I don't have one at my disposal. The application that I'm developping need to be used locally from any computer (can't use a localhost).

Comment: The localhost is your computer. The HSQLDB Server is a program that runs on your computer.

Comment: I don't really understand. I thought that you had to set up the localhost. How am I supposed to set up a database on my localhost using HSQLDB and at the start of the program? Do you have an example? The documentation is a little bit vague.

Comment: Thanks I thought that it would not work on Windows 7 but it did. But how am I supposed to run this command line on Java when running the program? I need a simple double click on my jar file to be enough to start the app (and start the server).

Comment: Nevermind I found what I needed by digging a little bit. I used http://hsqldb.org/doc/verbatim/src/org/hsqldb/test/TestBase.java. Thanks a lot.